# Firebase functions build fails due to dependencies

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just set up a new firebase project with functions.

Then I added a simple trigger function and wanted to deploy it.

When I run the build command `npm run build` (`tsc`) I get the following error message:

```
> functions@0.0.1 build {{PROJECT_PATH}}\firebase\functions
> tsc

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:504:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'Response<ResBody, StatusCode>' incorrectly extends interface 'ServerResponse'.
  Types of property 'req' are incompatible.
    Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IncomingMessage'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IncomingMessage'.

504 export interface Response<ResBody = any, StatusCode extends number = number> extends http.ServerResponse, Express.Response {
                     ~~~~~~~~

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/readable-stream/index.d.ts:19:15 - error TS2417: Class static side 'typeof _Readable' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Readable'.
  The types of 'Stream.Readable.Duplex' are incompatible between these types.
    Property 'isDisturbed' is missing in type 'typeof _Readable.Duplex' but required in type 'typeof import("stream").Duplex'.

19 declare class _Readable extends stream.Readable {
                 ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/stream.d.ts:59:20
    59             static isDisturbed(stream: Readable | NodeJS.ReadableStream): boolean;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'isDisturbed' is declared here.

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/readable-stream/index.d.ts:68:11 - error TS2720: Class 'Duplex' incorrectly implements class '_Readable'. Did you mean to extend '_Readable' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Type 'Duplex' is missing the following properties from type '_Readable': readableAborted, readableDidRead

68     class Duplex extends Writable implements /*extends*/_Readable, stream.Duplex {
             ~~~~~~

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/readable-stream/index.d.ts:68:11 - error TS2720: Class '_Readable.Duplex' incorrectly implements class 'import("stream").Duplex'. Did you mean to extend 'import("stream").Duplex' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Type 'Duplex' is missing the following properties from type 'Duplex': readableAborted, readableDidRead

68     class Duplex extends Writable implements /*extends*/_Readable, stream.Duplex {
             ~~~~~~

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/readable-stream/index.d.ts:111:11 - error TS2720: Class '_Readable.PassThrough' incorrectly implements class 'import("stream").PassThrough'. Did you mean to extend 'import("stream").PassThrough' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Type 'PassThrough' is missing the following properties from type 'PassThrough': readableAborted, readableDidRead

111     class PassThrough extends Transform implements stream.PassThrough {
              ~~~~~~~~~~~

../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/readable-stream/index.d.ts:173:11 - error TS2720: Class '_Readable.Transform' incorrectly implements class 'import("stream").Transform'. Did you mean to extend 'import("stream").Transform' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Type 'Transform' is missing the following properties from type 'Transform': readableAborted, readableDidRead

173     class Transform extends Duplex implements stream.Transform {
```

How can I resolve this issues? None of this dependencies are used directly in my code.

(For the example I reduced my code to a single function but the error did not change)
My Functions code:

```
index.ts
export {
  authUserCreatedTrigger
} from './user/auth-user.trigger';



config.ts
export const functionsRegion = 'europe-west1';
export const firestoreSettings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
export enum FirebaseCollection {
  User = 'user',
}



auth-user.trigger.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const firestore = admin.firestore();
firestore.settings(firestoreSettings);


const onCreateHandler = async (user: admin.auth.UserRecord, context: functions.EventContext) => {
  // Email is an required field
  if (!user.email) {
    return null;
  }

  // Disable user on default
  user = await admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid, {
    disabled: true,
  });

  // Split up user object
  const {uid, displayName, photoURL, email, phoneNumber, disabled} = user;

  // Get firestore user document ref
  const userDocumentRef = firestore.collection(FirebaseCollection.User).doc(uid);

  // Write new user to firestore
  return userDocumentRef.set({
    uid,
    displayName,
    photoURL,
    email,
    emailVerified: false,
    phoneNumber,
    disabled,
    deletedAt: null,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
  });
};

export const authUserCreatedTrigger = functions
    .region(functionsRegion)
    .auth
    .user()
    .onCreate(onCreateHandler);
```

Comment: Your question should show a minimal complete example of the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We need to be able to reproduce what you've done so we can better see what went wrong.  It's entirely possible you did something wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added my code to the question

Comment: Well I did not found the exact error but I guess it's due to something on my dev machine. After pulling the repo on my mac and installing node 14 I could deploy the functions without any problems.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am pretty sure that there are missing some` devDependencies` from `@types/**`. Look into my answer. I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue with a complete clean `firebase init` into an existing project. The errors you are seeing are `@types/*` errors within `node_modules`.

Which means that you have the following options:

**The quick and dirty**

in your `tsconfig.json` add `"skipLibCheck": true` to your `compilerOptions` block:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // (...) firebase standard init

    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  // other stuff
}
```

**The hard way**

read through your error messages and install the missing `@types/**` packages.
In a complete clean and fresh install can start with the following:

- `@types/node`
- `@types/express`
- (...)

Just keep an eye at these lines `../../../../../../../node_modules/@types/`